# Will my refrigerator be damaged by pump operation on the same circuit?

Tags: water, pump

I have a Samsung inverter fridge connected on the same circuit on automatic water pump that turns on and off to keep pressure in the pipes. Will it damage my fridge in the long term?

Answer (score 1):

The fridge should be designed to handle standard house hold equipment. With that said I would get a power strip that has surge suppressors in it to reduce the possibility of damage [like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00006B81E). if you get a supressor make sure it has indicator lights to show if the unit is still ok. Surge suppressors work by dumping the spikes to ground and when they take a large hit they are damaged. Once the suppressor fails the fridge will still work but the suppressor wont be dumping the spikes so one that has an indicator is best so you know that it is doing its job or it is time to replace it.